# is it possible to change the delta import command to delete the unwanted documents based on a criteria? each time when delta import runs

Tags: search, solr

I have dataImportScheduler configured which posts and HTTP request to import the increments or changes into the index. what I want to be able to do is each time when delta import runs it should run a delete query as well which has some criteria e.g. `documenttype:deleted` to delete the unwanted data in the index.

the delta import query i am using is

```
http://address:8080/solr-multicore/dataimport?command=delta-import&clean=false&commit=true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use deletedPkQuery to clean up the records which have been deleted.

[deletedPkQuery : Only used in delta-import](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler)

[Example](http://solr.pl/en/2011/01/03/data-import-handler-%E2%80%93-removing-data-from-index/) -

```
<entity name="album" query="SELECT * from albums" deletedPkQuery="SELECT deleted_id as id FROM deletes WHERE deleted_at > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">
```

This would help you to delete the records as well without the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible.
If you want to do delete only, you can remove both **deltaQuery** and **deltaImportQuery** and use the only **deletedPkQuery** as:

```
SELECT  id FROM db WHERE deletion = 1  AND solrsync_date > '${dataimporter.db.last_index_time}'"
```

Note:- Condition for delete can be anything.

And then run :
http://host:8983/solr/core/dataimport?command=delta-import

Comment: How is this different from the existing answer?

Comment: There was a confusion of whether we have can use deletedPkQuery only or we have to use it with delta query